# Spring declaration for interfaces with the same implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a problem with Spring.

I have two separate interfaces, findUnconditionalDiscountValuesStrategy and findConditionalDiscountValuesStrategy. These interfaces are implemented in the same class MmfgFindPricingWithCurrentPriceFactoryStrategy.

This is declared in the spring configuration file like this:

```
<alias name="mmfgFindPricingWithCurrentPriceFactoryStrategy" alias="currentFactoryFindPricingStrategy"/>
<bean id="mmfgFindPricingWithCurrentPriceFactoryStrategy" class="com.mmfg.mmfgacceleratorcore.order.strategies.calculation.impl.MmfgFindPricingWithCurrentPriceFactoryStrategy" parent="abstractBusinessService">
    <property name="findPricingWithCurrentPriceFactoryStrategy" ref="original-currentFactoryFindPricingStrategy"/>
    <property name="configurationService" ref="configurationService"/>
    <property name="mmfgSessionService" ref="mmfgSessionService"/>
    <property name="mmfgUtilsDao" ref="mmfgUtilsDao" />
</bean>
```

Now, I use the two interfaces in a class

```
private FindUnconditionalDiscountValuesStrategy findUnconditionalDiscountValuesStrategy;
private FindConditionalDiscountValuesStrategy findConditionalDiscountValueStrategy;
```

with getter and setter (getter **protected** and setter *@Required*).

Now I have declared this class in this way in the spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="mmfgOrderCalculationStrategy" class="com.mmfg.mmfgacceleratorcore.order.strategies.calculation.impl.DefaultMmfgOrderCalculationStrategy">
    <property name="findUnconditionalDiscountValuesStrategy" ref="currentFactoryFindPricingStrategy"/>
    <property name="findConditionalDiscountValuesStrategy" ref="currentFactoryFindPricingStrategy"/>
    <property name="modelService" ref="modelService" />
    <property name="commonI18NService" ref="commonI18NService" />
    <property name="calculationService" ref="calculationService"/>
</bean>
```

the *ref* is the same for the two interfaces, because the implementation class is the same.

But at runtime I obtain this error:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'findConditionalDiscountValueStrategy' is required for bean 'mmfgOrderCalculationStrategy'*

How I have to declare the *ref* in the two properties?

Comment: typo - your propery is called `findConditionalDiscountValueStrategy` (Value, not Values) in your class, but you attempt to set it as `findConditionalDiscountValuesStrategy` (Values)

Comment: You're right :( i'm a chicken...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo error. My property is called *findConditionalDiscount**Value**Strategy*. But in the class the name is *findConditionalDiscount**Values**Strategy*.